# How to set high water mark to block on flooded recipient in pyzmq?

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm confused by HWM behavior in PyZMQ.  I would expect the following code to block

#### Failing Example

```
In [1]: import zmq
In [2]: context = zmq.Context()

In [3]: alice = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
In [4]: alice.set_hwm(1)
In [5]: alice.setsockopt(zmq.RCVHWM, 1)  # just to be sure
In [6]: alice.bind('ipc://alice')

In [7]: bob = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
In [8]: bob.set_hwm(1)
In [9]: bob.connect('ipc://alice')

In [10]: bob.send(b'123')
In [11]: bob.send(b'123')  # This doesn't block
In [12]: bob.send(b'123')  # This doesn't block
In [13]: bob.send(b'123')  # This doesn't block
```

Either I don't understand HWM or I don't understand how to use it in Python.

#### Question

How does one achieve blocking on the sender side when the recipient is flooded with messsages?

Comment: You might have already noticed, that High-Water-Mark-ing **principles have been changed** in recent versions of ZeroMQ. **Which version do you implement your test against?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how HWM is supposed to work.  HWM only affects the operation of the socket you set it on.  So, when `alice` reaches her [HWM](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-setsockopt#toc28), she'll start [dropping messages](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-socket#toc7) *silently* - she provides no feedback to `bob`, so `bob` keeps on sending his messages.

The purpose of the High Water Mark is *not* to provide reliability to the message stream, it's *only* to protect a socket from crashing due to running out of memory.  It's your job to handle message reliability in your application, if you need it.